# IBM Worklight 6.1: Unable to install in Windows 7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have installed eclipse juno 4.2.2 but there is a problem in installing worklight

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630.jar. Read timed out Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.worklight-builder_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630-developer-edition.jar. Read timed out

Comment: Have you tried just downloading the plugin via HTTP/Download Director(or whatever IBM calls it these days) and installing from archive?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using one of these supported versions of Eclipse (for Worklight):

- Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)
- Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)

I have used Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 in Windows 7 as well, and installed Worklight via the Eclipse Marketplace (Help > Eclipse Marketplace > search for "worklight"). The installation finished successfully.

You either have a network issue, or the service was just temporary unavailable. Everything seems to be working OK now. In other words - try again.